# add image to the button

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here is the code for my button in the project, my requirement is i want to add some image(c:\1.jpg) before the button text "attach approval" and after the button is clicked the button name is changed to "approve" after it is changed i want to add another image(c:\2.jpg)

```
  <Button ToolTip="Attach Approval" 
        Height="25" Margin="5,10,5,10">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <!-- Default Content value -->
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding AddAttachmentCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Attach Approval">
                        </Setter>

                        <!-- Triggered values -->
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAttachmentAvailable}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Appprove"/>
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ApproveTemplateCommand}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAttachmentAvailable}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires using an explicit Style Value definition. For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="YourImagePath.jpg" />
                <TextBlock Text="Attach Approval" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You could set the `Content` property here to any container you like, and throw whatever elements you require inside.